Mongodb-community error on mongosh: mongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
I installed mongodb via brew and when I try to start the mongo process brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community and I try to see the services list brew services list I see the process is under error:
mongodb-community error  4 root     ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist

If I try to run mongosh as well:
Current Mongosh Log ID: 66a0ead8814d4423f0001234
Connecting to:      mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+2.2.12
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

This is my config file:
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/output.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1, ::1
  ipv6: true

The output.log is currently empty

Is the /usr/local/var/log/mongodb directory writable by the user account running mongod?

Same question for /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/output.log - is it writable?

Yes I did and the output still empty
